# Function doesn't return correct state

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to write a function to get a random color from an array COLORS. But, the problem is instead of returning only one color, it is returning too many colors, resulting in an infinite error. Resulting in which react throws Too many re-renders error. What's wrong with my code?

```
const COLORS = [
  "#FFAEBC",
  "#1ec891",
  "#ff725e",
  "#ffd05b",
  "#A0E7E5",
  "#5885AF",
];

const DisplaySubject = (props) => {

  const [randomColor, setRandomColor] = useState("");

  const generateRandomColor = (colors) => {
    let randColorIndex, randColor;
    for (let i = 0; i < colors.length; i++) {
      randColorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
      randColor = colors[randColorIndex];
      return randColor;
    }
    console.log(randColor);
    setRandomColor(randColor);
  };

  generateRandomColor(COLORS);

  console.log("random color state :", randomColor);
  return (
    <div>
      Let's get started
    </div>
  );
};

export default DisplaySubject;
```

Comment: dont iterate through the array to get a random index, literally just delete the for loop and keep the contents of the for loop

Comment: i don't see the need for a `for-loop`

Comment: I'm confused on how ```setRandom``` is even called? You're returning from your for loop

Answer (score 5, accepted):

First, fix your color generator function:

```js
const generateRandomColor = (colors) => {
    const randColorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    return colors[randColorIndex];
};
```

Then you can use it as the initial value for `useState`:

```js
const DisplaySubject = (props) => {
    const [randomColor, setRandomColor] = useState(generateRandomColor(COLORS));
    return (
        <div style={{ backgroundColor: randomColor }}>
            Let's get started
        </div>
    );
};
```

The problem was to call `setRandomColor` inside the `getRandomColor` function, that caused an infinite render cycle.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to iterate through the array to get a random element. Change your function like this:

```js
  const generateRandomColor = (colors) => {
    let randColorIndex, randColor;
    randColorIndex = Math.floor(Math.random() * colors.length);
    randColor = colors[randColorIndex];
    console.log(randColor);
    setRandomColor(randColor);
    return randColor;
  };
```

And the function gets called every time the component rerenders. So call the function on an event like `onClick` or if you want to run the function only once when the component renders for the first time, use `useEffect`:

```js
useEffect(() => generateRandomColor(COLORS), [])
```

Comment: Thanks, it was really helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Every time your component mounts, the function `generateRandomColor()`  is called and then it updates the state which causes a new render.

As an option, you can create a button and call this function with `onClick` event:

```
<button onClick={generateRandomColor(COLORS)}>generate a color</button>
```